# Answers with low score are no longer shown in gray text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

During the beta, answers with low score (score −3 or below if I remember correctly) were shown in gray text, but they are no longer shown in gray.

I guess that this change is unintentional, judging from the way the style sheet is written.  Namely, the style sheet still contains the declaration `.downvoted-answer {color: #888888;}` but it is effectively ignored because it is overridden by other declarations.

Comment: I'm looking into this. Do you happen to have a link to an answer with a lot of downvotes?

Comment: @Jin: Thanks!  Here is an example: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/circuit-complexity-charaterization-for-dlogtime-and-nlogtime/3838#3838

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have put in a fix, will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Verified.  Thanks!

Comment: For the record, this is fixed on Meta, too, although I do not know if Meta had the same problem or not in the first place.